# draw planes in matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection, plane

I have a problem since i'm beginner in matlab. x, y, z represent intersection between two planes, i draw one plane using surf, but cannot draw another one that is perpendicular to given plane...

```
    x=[727.572741489172,729.940373284625,732.253544909072,734.565600495015,736.832701046868,739.136844045222,741.376557764591,743.745619092508,746.046802707864,748.340161513939,750.656129504524];
y=[-61.8579712076452,-61.8579712076452,-61.7903997959850,-61.6928490578259,-61.6317429514839,-61.5443013249814,-61.1555441779056,-60.6298757082288,-60.6966982770352,-60.7473765546397,-60.5056492073855];
z=[-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.648242730349,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260,-369.533341483260];

plot3(x,y,z)
hold on
z1 = repmat(z',1,11);
a=z1';
surf(x,y,a,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor',[0 1 0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "cannot draw"? You don't know how to program it, or the way you do it doesn't work? In order to get a good answer, you need to be more specific.

Comment: I don't know how to program it, I have one surface with command surf(x,y,a,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor',[0 1 0])
but I'm having problems how to plot another surface that is on intersection line represented by x, y, z and perpendicular to first plane.